# How textureLoader.load for more than 1 texture and assigning map names to each texture?

Tags: three.js, textures

How can I call textureLoader.load only once and assign a map name to each texture and so that it I can call creating the material when all the textures have loaded?

Otherwise I can't control when to create the material and assign the textures correctly.

I am working with obj without loading mtl.

Thank you for your help

This is the code I'm asking to replace for one function textureLoader.load

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

var albedoM = textureLoader.load( "vaseTextures/albedo.png", onLoad, onProgress, onError );

var normalMap = textureLoader.load( "vaseTextures/normal.png", onLoad, onProgress, onError );

var aoMap = textureLoader.load( "vaseTextures/cavity.png", onLoad, onProgress, onError );   

Expected result: I call once function onLoad( texture) after the textures are loaded and saving a name for each texture, and so that I can then create one material that holds each texture and assign the textures to it.
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it's best to use the `onLoad()` callback of [THREE.LoadingManager](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager). It will be executed as soon as all resources are loaded. Since you already pass an instance of `THREE.LoadingManager` to your texture loader, you just have to implement `onLoad()`. For example like so:

```
manager.onLoad = function ( ) {

    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
    material.map = albedoM;
    material.normalMap = normalMap;
    material.aoMap = aoMap;

    // do something with your material

};
```

`three.js R103`

Comment: I added the object loader within the manager.onLoad function after assigning the textures to the material and it worked great, thank you !

Comment: Great. Oh, please don't forget to mark the answer as correct ;)